# D3js chart with 2 lines - display only lines

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am using library d3js, version 4, to draw on chart with 2 lines.
My data set has the flowing structure:

`[{x: "2021-01-25 00:09:46+0200", y: 0.108, yOut: 0.065}, {x: "2021-01-25 00:24:46+0200", y: 0, yOut: 0}]`

When i am tring to generate the chart this is rendered like this:

[image]

The code is the following

```
d3.select("svg#throughput").remove();
var svg = d3.select("#throughput")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("id", "throughput")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // add subtitle
        var minDate = d3.min(data, function (d) {
            return d.x;
        });
        var maxDate = d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.x;
        });

        var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z");

        var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return parseDate(d.x);
            }))
            .range([0, width]);

        var dateFormat = determineTicks(minDate, maxDate);

        var yInMin = d3.min(data, function (d) {
            return parseFloat(d.y);
        });
        var yInMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return parseFloat(d.y);
        });

        var yOutMin = d3.min(data, function (d) {
            return parseFloat(d.yOut);
        });
        var yOutMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return parseFloat(d.yOut);
        });

        var yMin = d3.min([yInMin, yOutMin]);
        var yMax = d3.max([yInMax, yOutMax]);

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([yMin, yMax])
            .range([height, 0]);

        var yOutScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([yOutMin, yOutMax])
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                .ticks(dateFormat.ticks)
                .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat(dateFormat.format))
            );

        var yAxis = svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

        var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0);

     

        // define the 1st line
        var valueline = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.x)) })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(parseFloat(d.y)) });

        // define the 2nd line
        var valueline2 = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.x)) })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(parseFloat(d.yOut)) });

        var line = svg.append('g')
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")


        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("d", valueline);

        // Add the valueline2 path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("d", valueline2);
```

I want to generate one chart looking like this: [image]

Please help me understand why the lines (1 and 2) are filled this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have many numbers as strings? This can explain why you need the parseFloat for the d.yIn.

The problem is that defined is applied to the original data, so it doesn't uses your parseFloat transformation.

Try using the following and let me know if it worked.

Obs: Most likely you don't even need to use the parseFloat on either conditions, but I've no fast way to test it.

```
var valueline = d3.line()
        .defined(function (d) { return !isNaN(parseFloat(d.yIn));  })
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.x)) })
        .y(function(d) {
            return yScale(parseFloat(d.yIn));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may reside in your data. For what I can see from the chart, it seems that the line is going to zero many times, so either you should filter the zeros or check for NaN's

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now another issue :(.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer! I tried to ignore NaN's data and the result is kinda oky (see the picture 1)[image]

After that, i didn't want to draw the line on the points where no data using the following method and the result is the in picture 2. I dont know whats is wrong with this :([image]

```
 // define the 1st line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .defined(function (d) { return (typeof d.yIn == 'number');  })
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.x)) })
        .y(function(d) {
            return yScale(Number(parseFloat(d.yIn)));
        });
```